# Вопрос по вызову .Dispose()

Tags: c#

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
   {
       // code
A: }
B:
```

Если для command метод .Dispose() вызывается в метке А, то для connection этот метод будет вызываться в метке B, сразу после вызова для command?

А в данном случае .Dispose() для connection всё равно вызовется в метке B?

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
   {
       // code
A: }
// code
B:
```

Comment: Можно считать, что да. А с чего такой вопрос?

Comment: Да. Считайте, что для внешнего using есть «невидимый» `{}`-блок.

Comment: Сомневаетесь - пишите вторые `{}`, займет у вас это секунду.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Код:

```
using (X)
using (Y)
{
    // code
}
```

эквивалентен коду:

```
using (X)
{
    using (Y)
    {
        // code
    }
}
```

а он в свою очередь разворачивается в *примерно* такой код:

```
try
{
    try
    {
        // code
    }
    finally
    {
        Y.Dispose();
    }
}
finally
{
    X.Dispose()
}
```

Т.о. `Dispose()` будет вызываться в порядке, обратном объявленному в `using`, и после выполнения кода внутри блока.